# How to construct a sentence that’s correct, using についての?

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, syntax

I know the sentence structure XについてのY, but I don’t know how to effectively use it. I know that what precedes it must be a noun or has to be nominalised, but still can’t figure out how to use it properly.

My best guess would be something like:

> ベルギー人はビール**について**の考え方とはベルギーのが一番美味しいと思います。
>  Belgian people’s views about beer are that Belgian beer is the best tasting.

Would that be a correct sentence? I wasn’t sure about how to use some of the particles with this construction.

[image: The information page on について / についての in my grammar book.]
(This is where I first learned about the construction.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「ベルギー人{じん}**は**ビールについての考{かんが}え方{かた}とはベルギーのが一番美味{いちばんおい}しいと**思{おも}います**。」

Before discussing the validity of your sentence above, I would like to talk about a couple of items.

> 「Noun 1 + に + ついて + **の** + Noun 2」

will always be a ***noun phrase***; therefore, it will need to be treated as such without an exception.

This differs from the expression:

> 「Noun + に + ついて + Verb」

which is a verb phrase.

Now, let us take a look at:

> 「ビール + に + ついて + の + 考え方」

That is a perfectly formed noun phrase.

Your sentence, however, has two flaws even though it was a very nice try.

1) The 「は」 after the 「ベルギー人」.  It needs to be 「の」 for it to be grammatical.  You said "Belgian people’s views" yourself; You used the "'s", which is 「の」 in Japanese.

2) 「思います」 at the end.  The subject of this sentence is 「考え方」 and ***not*** 「ベルギー人」.  You cannot say 「考え方は/が思います」 (even though you can say 「ベルギー人は/が思います」).

Ideally (and naturally), this sentence should end in 「～～という**もの**です」.  If you used 「考え方」 as the subject, you would use that 「もの」 to correspond to it within the predicate.

You used "views about beer ***are that*** ~~~" in your English.  The Japanese expression that is closest in both meaning and feeling to "is/are that ~~~" would be 「～～というものです」.

Thus, the sentence I would personally recommend would be:

> 「ベルギー人**の**ビールについての考え方とは、ベルギーのが一番美味しい**というものです**。」

A very natural use of 「の」 in 「ベルギーのが」 by you, by the way.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it in high detail. I think I understand it now. 考え方 is the subject so that’s the only part that should take the は or an equivalent to it. After ベルギー人 I should have placed a の because I’m talking about views ‘of’ Belgian people. I can’t use と思う because it’s not about the people, but about their views. I should use というものです because it’s the thing I’m describing. And thank you for being supportive and also pointing out what I did right. Very much obliged!